# Wrapping add_query_arg with esc_url not working

Tags: urls, escaping, wp-remote-get

I know about the XSS issue related to `add_query_arg()`function. That is why I am wrapping it with `esc_url()`.

Problem is...this is not working with `wp_remote_get()`.

If I go:

```
$url = add_query_arg( array( 'email' => 'myadress@mail.com', 
'token' => '899A762614F6C49809A374FB955EC8C15'),
'https://example.com/v3/transactions/notifications/3FF732-68B436B43622-3664083FB82B-CFB043' );
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );
```

I am getting a valid body response.

But if I use esc_url on the `$url`:

```
$url = esc_url(add_query_arg( array( 'email' => 'myadress@mail.com', 
'token' => '899A762614F6C49809A374FB955EC8C15'),
'https://example.com/v3/transactions/notifications/3FF732-68B436B43622-3664083FB82B-CFB043' ));
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );
```

The body response is "Unauthorized".

And the strange part: both codes echo the same string for $url!!!

Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And the strange part: both codes echo the same string for $url!!!

No, they don't. Look at the page source. `esc_url()` is encoding the `&` control character. You can't do that and expect the HTTP request to work correctly.

Use `esc_url_raw()` instead. Note the description in the Codex concerning that function:

> The esc_url_raw() function is similar to esc_url() (and actually uses
>   it), but unlike esc_url() it does not replace entities for display.
>   **The resulting URL is safe to use in** database queries, redirects and **HTTP requests**.
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw

Comment: Yes, the source code showed that, in fact. And I didn't know about `esc_url_raw()`. Thanks for that!